# Music video where a female astronaut sells her body parts to pay for a trip to her desired destination

Tags: story-identification, music-video

About 8-10 years ago, I remember watching this absolutely fascinating music video while waiting in a Hard Rock Café. While I unfortunately cannot recall specifics about the song itself, the video stuck with me and is something I can recall quite clearly in parts.

The video centered on a woman who appeared to be either a space explorer/pirate or an astronaut, trying to fix her broken ship with insufficient funds. She continually sells off various limbs and other parts of her body to pay for the parts necessary to make repairs, and the video ends with her taking off, with only her head sitting in the pilot's seat. I cannot remember if where she was headed was home or some desirable destination or not though. I'm also uncertain about whether the protagonist of the video was the artist herself, although it's very likely.

The video was in English, but I'm uncertain as to whether the artist was American or not, despite hearing the song in the United States. My only other guesses would be Great Britain, Canada, or Australia for where the song and artist originate, but I'm fairly certain the artist was American.

An exact timeline of when the video was made is difficult to estimate, since while I saw it about 8-10 years ago, there's a chance that it was around before then. Based on the quality of production though, I'd say it was produced pretty close to the time in which I saw it.

The style of music is also a bit vague in my mind, but I do seem to remember it being some form of rock, which would fit with the Hard Rock Café obviously.

I'd really like to find this again if I can because if nothing else, the video was just bizarre and interesting to me and it's something I'd like to revisit. I'm also open to questions for further clarification since there may be something I'm not remembering right this very second that could help find it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Broken Bells -- The Ghost Inside

Wikipedia calls them an indie rock band. This song is from their self-titled debut album, which was released in 2010--which, much to my shock, was 8 years ago.

The video features a woman who sells her body parts to pay for fuel to travel through space to some sort of paradise. It doesn't end with her becoming a head though.

> After losing several limbs, she crashes into an asteroid and is left for dead. Then she's recovered and given artificial body parts to replace the ones she lost, and arrives at her destination only to find a ruined wasteland.

Comment: Sequel; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhBewKu80Mg

Comment: Worth pointing out "a woman" is none other than Christina Hendricks, perhaps her first sci-fi role since *Firefly*.

Comment: Aha! This is the one I remember, although I'm not sure where I picked up the head detail though... Possibly a different video but I'd be hard-pressed to try and find that one too if that's the only thing I remember. Anyway, thank you!